# How to show popups at validations?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popover

I have two different codes related to my problem. I just want to combine them for proper working.

I have tried every possible condition known to me. I am a beginner to javascript.

```
<script>
        function AllowAlphabet(e) {
            isIE = document.all ? 1 : 0
            keyEntry = !isIE ? e.which : event.keyCode;
            if (((keyEntry >= '65') && (keyEntry <= '90')) || ((keyEntry >= '97') && (keyEntry <= '122')) || (keyEntry == '46') || (keyEntry == '32') || keyEntry == '45')
                return true;
            else {

                alert('Alphabets Only...!!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

-------------------------
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" onkeydown="allLetter(inputtxt);" onkeypress="return AllowAlphabet(event)" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
```

** I want to combine these scripts. I want to run the second script in the else part of the first script.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like below would help. Just put the call to `AllowAlphabet` in `document.ready` and update the else statement as follow.

```
function AllowAlphabet(e) {
    isIE = document.all ? 1 : 0
    keyEntry = !isIE ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if (((keyEntry >= '65') && (keyEntry <= '90')) || ((keyEntry >= '97') && (keyEntry <= '122')) || (keyEntry == '46') || (keyEntry == '32') || keyEntry == '45')
        return true;
    else {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        alert('Alphabets Only...!!');
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     AllowAlphabet();
});
```

However if you want to call `AllowAlphabet` somewhere else in your code, you do not need to wrap it in `document.ready`.

**UPDATE**
It seems that you are using `onkeypress` event listener in order to call the `AllowAlphabet` function. In this case, because document is ready at that moment, using `document.ready` is not needed anymore. Just put the `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` in your else statement as above.

Comment: can you please now look at my asp.net code and guide me...?

Comment: Try to put `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` in your else statement as described, it should work

Comment: any help please...??